# Paypal Gateway integration error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal-sandbox

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to a member function getMessage() on null

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\paypl\application\libraries\PayPal-PHP-SDK\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\sample\common.php

Line Number: 119

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\paypl\application\controllers\Paypal.php
Line: 103
Function: printError

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\paypl\index.php
Line: 293
Function: require_once
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for what is a null variable on which you try to run method.

Go to `C:\xampp\htdocs\paypl\application\libraries\PayPal-PHP-SDK\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\sample\common.php` to line 119 and see on what variable `getMessage()` is tried to be called.

It will be null but shouldn't - you will then have to find why that variable is null, it might be missing config, some network error, missing some DB connection etc.